# Как найти худшее значение в в каждой матрице из листа

Tags: r

Всем привет,
У меня есть дата фрейм в котором собраны больницы из всех штатов США с процентом смертности по 3 болезням.
У меня задание написать функцию которая принимала бы как аргументы название болезни и место в рейтинге, а на выходе показывала бы матрицу с 2 колонками. В первой колонке штат во второй имя больницы с рейтингом смертности который мы присвоили, по болезни которую мы указали.
Саму функция я написал.

```
rankall <- function(outcome, rank) {
setwd("C:/Users/nbobukh/R/ProgrammingAssignment3")
outcome_t <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character") ##считал нужный файл
if(outcome == "heart attack") {
outcome <- 11
} else if(outcome == "heart failure") {
outcome <- 17
} else if(outcome == "pneumonia"){
outcome <- 23
} else {
warning()
stop()
} ##для каждой болезни присвоил номер столбца где хранится информация
outcome_t[, outcome] <- as.numeric(outcome_t[, outcome])
outcome_t <- outcome_t[order(outcome_t[, 7], outcome_t[, outcome]), ] ##отсортировал по штату и проценту смертности
work_list <- split(outcome_t, outcome_t$State) ##поделил по штату
answer <- sapply(work_list, function(x) x[rank, c(2,7)])
cbind(answer[1, ], answer[2, ])
}
```

Сам код работает корректно, но вот в задании есть пометка, что если я ввожу "worst" как аргумент rank, то в списке должны быть названия больниц с худшими показателями. В каждом штате разное количество больниц.

Не могу реализовать не именно это часть. 
Очень надеюсь на помощь.